# How to include native .so with JAR

Tags: java-native-interface, executable-jar

I'm building a JAR file (to run on linux servers) which uses a native libxxxx.so file. I can put the .so file anywhare and pass its locattion using -Djava.library.path option.

Now can I include the .so file with the jar so that I don't have to copy it to a location and include its location when I'll run the jar?

Comment: That sounds like a clever race condition that I could use to splat out my own library onto disk before you and make you start running my native code!

Comment: Agreed! I think I will not pack the library with the jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately you'll have to unpack it from the jar and store it somewhere before the system will be able to use it.  Java Web Start has support for delivering native libraries, but even that system requires it to copy the native libraries out of their delivery jar files into a temporary location.

[JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) provides [support for embedding and unpacking a shared library](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/NativeLibrary.html) from anywhere in your resource path (usually a jar file, but anywhere accessible by `Class.getResource()` will do).